# Change Page Title

Tags: functions, title, json, variables

I have successfully changed the name of a specific page using this code in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_my_property_title');

function change_my_property_title($title) {
     if ( is_page('property') ) {
       return 'Property';
     }
     return $title;
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to change the name to an actual php variable that is on the property page.  I am pulling property information from a json url and would like the address to be the title.  If I try to point to the variable in my return statement nothing comes up.

Here is the page I'm working on: http://geekoutaustin.com/live/property/?id=d86967ad43c2f5271b02f94247ef858d&wpf28382_5=8252427

Comment: How are you defining this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  By using the functions.php page I wasn't able to use variables defined on the page I wanted to create custom titles for.  I ended up adding the below code to my custom page php.

```
<?php $newtitle = ucwords($mlsa->StreetNumber . ' '  . $mlsa->StreetName . ' ' . $mlsa->StreetSuffix.', '. $mlsa->City); ?>
<script>document.title = "<?php echo $newtitle; ?>";</script>
```

or a more simple version:

```
<?php $newtitle = $someVariable; ?>
<script>document.title = "<?php echo $newtitle; ?>";</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your template is using the_title you can override it by adding this filter to your function

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_my_property_title' );
```

Comment: I don't think that's the part OP needs help with.

Comment: ^ I can already change the name of the page to a specific string but I'm looking to make the page an actual variable that is found on the page itself.  Putting a variable in the functions.php doesn't work.